# Testing full-text search with textacular and cucumber throws PG::Error: ERROR: function similarity(character varying, unknown) does not exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, full-text-search, cucumber

I've got textacular working in my app but my features are blowing up. The following code:

```
Background:
  Given the following "project" records:
    | name      |
    | Project 1 |
    | Project 2 |
  And I am on "the projects page"

Scenario: Find projects by content
  When I search for "Project 1"
  Then I should see the project called "Project 1" in the project list
```

Blows up with this message:

```
When I search for "Project 1" # features/step_definitions/search_steps.rb:11

  PG::Error: ERROR:  function similarity(character varying, unknown) does not exist
  LINE 1: SELECT "projects".*, similarity("projects"."name", 'Project\...

  HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
  : SELECT "projects".*, similarity("projects"."name", 'Project\ 1') AS "rank79552331411843676" FROM "projects"  WHERE (("projects"."name" % 'Project\ 1'))  ORDER BY "rank79552331411843676" DESC (ActionView::Template::Error)
```

I've got the Trigram module installed in Postgres, as I'm using fuzzy search, and everything works fine in development. I don't fully understand what this error message means. Here's a little more of my code:

```
# search_steps.rb
When(/^I search for "(.*?)"$/) do |query|
  fill_in 'query', with: query
  click_button 'Search'
end

# GET /projects
def index
  @projects = Project.search(params[:query])
end

# project.rb
def self.search(query)
  return all unless query.present?
  fuzzy_search(query)
end
```

Has anyone encountered and fixed this before?

Comment: Are you setting up `pg_trgm` in your test database too?

Comment: Yes I am successully running `bundle exec rake textacular:install_trigram` before running my features. And I still get this error occurring.

Comment: But does that install the PostgreSQL extension into your test database?

Comment: @muistooshort, the problem was being caused by me running 'rake cucumber' instead of just 'cucumber'. When you run it with rake, you also run db:setup, which resets the db and removes trigram. So it's fixed now, thanks for your help.

Comment: You might want to put that down as an answer, seems like a simple enough mistake that lots of people will make it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone else out there who runs into this issue, you can run `bundle exec rake textacular:install_trigram` all you like, but if you use rake to run cucumber or rspec, then db:test:prepare is invoked, and since trigram is not being installed through a migration, this has the effect of wiping it from the db when the schema is loaded!

```
# install trigram in test db
bundle exec rake textacular:install_trigram RAILS_ENV=test

# wipe trigram from db
rake cucumber
rake rspec
```

To stop this from happening, just run cucumber and rspec without rake!

```
# run cucumber and rspec without rake
cucumber
rpsec
```

What a horrible problem! 2 days to fix etc...

Answer (score 0):

The real solution here is to use SQL instead of Active Record's schema dumper for your database schema file. So, instead of a `db/schema.rb` file, you should have a `db/structure.sql` file. You can do this by uncommenting the following line in your `config/application.rb` file:

```
config.active_record.schema_format = :sql
```

What's going on is that your test database is dropped and recreated each time you run your tests. But it's recreated using your `db/schema.rb` file, which doesn't contain any information about the PostgreSQL extensions you have installed, since it is meant to be database agnostic. In order to reinstall your Postgres extensions when the test database is recreated, you need the schema in SQL format.

Also, to avoid confusion in the future, you may want to remove the `db/schema.rb` file after you make this switch. And you may need to rollback and then run a migration to get the schema dumped to SQL (I can't remember for sure if this is necessary, and am too lazy to test it).